# Local variable definied in an if statement hehaves unexpectedly

Tags: c++, cross-platform, undefined-behavior

Originally I wanted to pack a bunch of statement into a single line so my stuff can be used as a simple macro inside an if.
I needed to do 3 things:

- Create a local variable
- Update that with a function
- Check if the updated variable matches something else

Here's my quick draft code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
#define MAGIC_VALUE 42

bool MyMockedFunction(uint64_t* outElement)
{
    *outElement = MAGIC_VALUE;

    return true;
}

static const uint64_t global_should_match_this = MAGIC_VALUE;

int main()
{
    // Originally I wanted to declare the variable in one single line (as a defined macro, which should be used in an IF statement)
    // That's why I have so many things packed into the same line
    // It may or may not (latter is more probable) a good idea, but that's not the question here

    if (uint64_t generatedElement = 123456 && MyMockedFunction(&generatedElement) && global_should_match_this == generatedElement)
    {
        // I would expect generatedElement == MAGIC_VALUE
        printf("Inside value: %llu\n", generatedElement);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Unmatched\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I understand that programatically it may not be foolproof and it's prone to misuse if I put it in a macro (also macros are evil), but in my case it would be a very controlled environment, just to make my code easier to read.

So, the question is here - why the generatedElement equals to 1 after running? Is it an undefined behaviour in any way?

I've checked in a compiler disassembler that it's 1 because in the end the comparison's value (is the expression true? yes -> 1 -> that's what is moved into the variable. But it looks unreasonable to me. Why would a compiler do so? :O Checked both on MSVC & GCC, both produces the same output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your condition is really:

```
uint64_t generatedElement = (123456 && MyMockedFunction(&generatedElement) && global_should_match_this == generatedElement)
```

Which means you initialize `generatedElement` with the *boolean result*. And also lead to *undefined behavior* as you use the *uninitialized* (and indeterminate) value of `generatedElement`.

If your compiler support [`if` statements with initializer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#If_Statements_with_Initializer) (new in C++17) then you can do

```
if (uint64_t generatedElement = 123456; MyMockedFunction(&generatedElement) && global_should_match_this == generatedElement)
{
    // ...
}
```

Otherwise you have to split up into separate variable definition and condition:

```
uint64_t generatedElement = 123456;
if (MyMockedFunction(&generatedElement) && global_should_match_this == generatedElement)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: The write to `generatedElement` that would occur while executing `MyMockedFunction` is sequenced before the read in the comparison.  Unfortunately, while the Standard allows an object which is being initialized to have its address taken within its initialization expression, I think the intention is to allow for situations where the resulting pointer won't be used to access the associated storage until after the initialization completes.